# Running a query in R after establishing dbconnect

Tags: r, sql, data-formats

I do not seem to figure out what is wrong it the following statement. The connection to the DWH is established but the query statement in R seems not to work, with the following error :

```
LR=dbGetQuery(con, "select id as ID,
       date_c."Professional_Status" as Prof_Status,
       case when talk_sec >= 5 then 1 else 0 end as Established_Connection
from id_collect as id_c
left join date_conncet as date_c on id_c.date=date_c.date
where date::date = '2018-01-19' and country = 'IT' and type = 'shop' 
              and 'district' = 'South' and interaction is true")
```

This piece of query runs in the SQL editor (using Postgresql) but in R I get the error message: Error: unexpected symbol in "  or unexpected numeric constant. I do use the following:

```
install.packages("RPostgreSQL")
install.packages("DBI")
library(RPostgreSQL)
```

I believe it is not about the syntax but the quote I use, what's the proper quote etiquette in R when using numeric vs. categorical values? The whole select statement must begin and end with "select ...." correct?

Also to add how to establish a connection to your DTW (add your DWH info):

```
con <- dbConnect(RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL(),
    dbname="DBNAME",
    host= "HOSTNAME",
    port=0000,
    user="youruser",
    password="yourpassword")
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question as: I try to send this query to the database but it doesn't work.
As far as I can see the trouble is here:

```
"select id as ID,
       date_c."Professional_Status" as
```

You first start with double quotes and R thinks that the string ends at the next double quotes, so before Professional_Status. Use either single quotes like you do in `date = '2018-01-19'`
Or use single quotes at the ends and double in between. Don't mix and match, it will not work. 
Since Profesional status is not defined variable nor is it a valid R statement this will fail.

Some small tips:
If you want to substitute professional_status with a variable you have defined in your R session, use something like `paste("text", variable " text")` or use the excellent glue package that allows you to write `glue("text {variable} text")` 
A final tip, if you use an IDE, like for instance RStudio, you can actually see that the text ends at the first second quote, because the highlighting is different.

Comment: That makes sense, so I will start and end the select statement with "" but cannot use it for variables within the statement. I adjusted that, however, now I get this error, any ideas what is causing this? _Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
DETAIL:  User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed._